# Как получить название объекта js?

Tags: php, javascript

Я пытаюсь сделать функцию которая из `Object` с `CSS`:

```
{
  width: "100px",
  height: "100px",
  backgroundColor: "rgba(123,12,123,1)"
}
```

Нужному элементу присваивала бы все эти стили.

Дело в том что в php я бы сделал вот так:

```
foreach ($Object as $key => $value) {
    $element.style[$key] = $value;
}
```

Как реализовать такое в `JS` ?

P.s. Я знаю что `$element.style[$key] = $value;` неправильный код, надеюсь вы поняли что я имел ввиду в этом примере.

Comment: Можно ли использовать библиотеку jQuery? в тегах её нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в JQ примерно так это реализованно

```
function css(prop, value) {
   /* ф-ция выполняется в контексте элемента
      поэтому this уже ссылается на него */
   var el = this;
   if(typeof prop == 'string' || value != undefined) {
       el.style[prop] = value;
   } else if (typeof prop == 'object') {
       for(var i in prop) el.style[i] = prop[i];
   }
}


/* добавим в прототип нашу ф-цию */
HTMLElement.prototype.css = css;

/* Теперь используем */
document.body.css("background", "black"); // можно так
// или так
document.body.css({
    "background" : "black",
    "marginTop" : "150px"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String.prototype.camelCaseToDash = function () {
    return this.replace(/([A-Z])/g, function ($1) {
        return "-" + $1.toLowerCase();
    });
};
var obj = {
    width: "100px",
    height: "100px",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(123,12,123,1)"
},
cssStr = '';
for (var k in obj) {
    cssStr += k.camelCaseToDash() + ':' + obj[k] + ';'
}
document.getElementById('my-element-id').style.cssText = cssStr;
```

[Пример в песочнице](http://jsfiddle.net/eL23n474/)

Comment: `style.cssText` заменяет _все текущие стили_ элемента вместо добавления новых. Почему бы не использовать выражения вида `el.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(123,12,123,1)';`? Тогда и конвертировать название свойств в другой формат не придется :)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, если нужно добавить или изменить существующие свойства прописанные в атрибуте style, то да, можно и так. Однако, для такой операции, мой код нужно увеличить только на один символ "**+**":  `document.getElementById('my-element-id').style.cssText += cssStr;` [Для примера](http://jsfiddle.net/eL23n474/2/)

Comment: для случая добавления свойств ваш код можно _существенно сократить_ выкинув `String.prototype.camelCaseToDash` :)

Answer (score 0):

Если использовать jQuery, то можно как-то так:

```
var style = {
    width: "100px",
    height: "100px",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(123,12,123,1)"
};

var $el = $('.target-element');

for (var key in style) {
    if (!style.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        continue;
    }

    $el.css(key, style[key]);
}
```

**UPD:**

В комментариях справедливо подсказывают, что можно проще:

```
var style = {
    width: "100px",
    height: "100px",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(123,12,123,1)"
};

$('.target-element').css(style);
```

Comment: Вы удивитесь, но для jQuery никаких дополнительных [телодвижений не нужно](http://jsfiddle.net/eL23n474/1/) :)) Просто передаете в метод объект `$('.target-element').css(style);
`

Comment: Да, действительно. Как-то забыл об этой опции. Подправил ответ.